# Get RadGrid row value through a button column in the grid

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik

I have a column with a button in my radgrid, I want to be able to click the button and get the values of the row in which the button is located on. This must be done without selecting the row, I remember seeing a part of code my friend wrote in which he used ".Parent" or something similar to get the row from of the button column clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you click any button in the GridButtonColumn of a RadGrid, you can access the button's row and the row's values by doing the following:

In the RadGrid's definition, add `OnItemCommand="RadGrid1_ItemCommand"`.

In the GridButtonColumn's definition, set its command name with something like `CommandName="Test"`.

Now add the following to your code-behind to access whatever column you want.  In my sample code below I get the value in the column "Whatever":

```
protected void RadGrid1_ItemCommand(object sender, GridCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "Test")
    {
        GridDataItem item = (GridDataItem)e.Item;
        string columnWhateverValue = item["Whatever"].Text;
    }
}
```